# implementing read operation using M-SPI between BCM7358 and SPI NOR

Tags: embedded, spi, flash-memory

SPI subsystem sitting between BCM7358 and SPI NOR flash use B-SPI module to perfrom read operation and M-SPI module to perfrom the write operation....If I have to perfrom read operation from M-SPI as an substitute of B-SPI...then how can I proceed....any suggestion are welcomed

Comment: The problem with Broadcom is that as I understand it they only make their data sheets available to licensed users of their chips.  If your product uses one of those devices you must have access to that information, but anyone else with that information would probably be contravening *their* license if they were to post specific details here.  If you know different then post a link to the datasheet or user reference.  As it stands I have no idea what M-SPI and B-SPI refer to; SPI is SPI and is bidirectional.

Comment: @Lucifer: Not really a superuser question IMO.  It just needs fixing to make it clear how this is an embedded programming issue.  It may be a question for a Broadcom field engineer!

Comment: @Clifford now you have changed the question.

Comment: @Clifford: Actually I got the answer of the previous question and get stuck at this point...so I have modified the question.

Comment: @Clifford: Ye this is Broadcom specific...M-SPI(Master SPI) and B-SPI (Boot SPI)...but here m not looking for the exact solution...might be somebody can tell me a generic approach...

Comment: One wonders why you replaced the meaningful descriptions of the interfaces in your original question which abbreviations that are only meaningful to those with past experience of this particular family of SOC's.

Comment: @Lucifer:  I never changed a thing. Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to find the programming information for the master spi interface, or else find a driver module compatible with your OS or example code you can crib from.

Assuming you want to do the access while your system is running rather than in order to boot from the SPI, what you want to do seems pretty reasonable so the chances of finding useful information are good.

If you are trying to do this to boot, you may need to boot a small bootloader from something else which can "manually" load an image with the master spi and then jump into it.  Or else see if the chip has a mode pin combination or the like to boot from the master spi interface instead.

Essentially, if you made your own board and sourced chips without data sheets, you are in trouble unless you can find something else using a similar enough chip to crib from.  Similarly if you are hacking a modification to a product without any source code.  But if you bought an eval board or module, presumably you have access to some documentation or example code for the board, even if not for the chip.

Comment: Thanks all...hacked the board...with the help of Broadcom registers details....I have implemented it.